# Post request with form-data via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a ec2 server and it's using CloudFront because it needs to use https with cerificate signed by AWS. And then there is some API inside this ec2 server that i need to use post method with form-data. but the server somehow can't get the form-data. Is there some cache policy that i have to set? or CloudFront is purposedly forcing me to do everything with the API gateway thing?

Comment: "somehow can't get the form-data" - this is not specific. What exactly is happening? What are your CF distro and cache behaviour setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your setup that uses Cloudfront to terminate TLS and forward HTTP requests to EC2 is fine.

You can try turning on forwarding all **Query strings** and see if it works for you

[image]